# Flex component - When resized, resize all inner components

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, components, resize

My component has lots of inner components.
When i resize the container component (panel), i want all inner components resize with same ratio. Which function should i use?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FkLYc.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width and height to a percentage instead of a hard-coded value.

```
<s:Panel title="Flexible Container" backgroundColor="0x00FF00"
        width="75%" height="75%">
        <s:TextArea id="mTA" height="100%" width="100%" 
            text="Text Area Resize" />
</s:Panel>
```